# Is there a square matrix with applications in Cryptography such that the determinant of this matrix is 0 and all its sub minors are non-singular?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, linear-cryptanalysis, matrix-multiplication, diffusion

I am looking for a square matrix whose determinant is 0, however, all sub-minors of this matrix are non singular. This matrix needs to have applications in Cryptography. The matrix may be over any Galois field of type 2^r. Please provide an example and references. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the reason for this rather specific question?

Comment: @poncho We are looking for non-MDS matrices with real life applications in Cryptography. Thanks.